# Testing SWT application using SWTBot:

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, gui-testing, swtbot, swt-awt

**Testing SWT application with SWTBot:**

I came across one requirement, where I need to test an SWT application using SWTBot. I had no idea how to start with SWTBot, after referring few blogs I can setup the SWTBot using eclipse. And also I found that most of the tutorials describes the testing of an Eclipse plug-in but I couldn't find anything regarding my requirement (like testing third party SWT application). I don't even know whether it is possible or not.

**My Requirement -** I have one JNLP file and after running this JNLP file SWT application will open. Once application opens I have to login to the application using UserID and Pwd. I am trying with below code bur its trowing an exception "WidgetNotFoundException".

***Code***

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.SWTBot;
import org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.utils.SWTBotPreferences;
import org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.waits.Conditions;
import org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.widgets.SWTBotButton;
import org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.widgets.SWTBotText;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestLogin {
    @Test
    public void verifyLogin() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        // Set the timeout to 6 seconds
        SWTBotPreferences.TIMEOUT = 6000;

        //Launch the SWT applicaton.
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javaws C:\\Users\\anand\\Downloads\\Testing.jnlp");
        Thread.sleep(60000);

        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display); 
        SWTBot bot = new SWTBot(shell);

        //"User Authentication" is the name of the login window
        bot.waitUntil(Conditions.shellIsActive("User Authentication")); 
        bot.shell("User Authentication").activate(); 

        bot.activeShell();
        bot.textWithLabel("User ID:").setText("anand");
        bot.textWithLabel("Password:").setText("anand123");
        bot.button("Login").click();

        /*       
        SWTBotText userID = bot.textWithLabel("User ID:");
        SWTBotText passwordText = bot.textWithLabel("Password:");
        SWTBotButton loginButton = bot.button("Login");

        userID.setFocus();
        userID.setText("Superman");
        //assert(userID.getText().equals("Superman"));

        passwordText.setFocus();
        passwordText.setText("test123");
        //assert(userID.getText().equals("test123"));

        loginButton.setFocus();
        loginButton.click();   
        */
    }
}
```

***Output:***

```
org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.exceptions.WidgetNotFoundException: Could not find shell matching: with text 'User Authentication'
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.SWTBotFactory.waitUntilWidgetAppears(SWTBotFactory.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.SWTBotFactory.shells(SWTBotFactory.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.SWTBotFactory.shell(SWTBotFactory.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.SWTBotFactory.shell(SWTBotFactory.java:97)
    at com.fis.teller.testscripts.TestLogin.verifyLogin(TestLogin.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.widgets.TimeoutException: Timeout after: 6000 ms.: Could not find shell matching: with text 'User Authentication'
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.SWTBotFactory.waitUntil(SWTBotFactory.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.SWTBotFactory.waitUntil(SWTBotFactory.java:496)
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.SWTBotFactory.waitUntil(SWTBotFactory.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.SWTBotFactory.waitUntilWidgetAppears(SWTBotFactory.java:466)
    ... 27 more
```

I think that I'm not able to transfer the the control to "User Authentication" shell/Widget/window.

Answer (score 0):

Is it maybe because the shell is not even present yet, therefore waiting for it to be active will fail?

For me iterating through all views, and then matching them by title works better, even when it's not the cleanest coded. You could have a separate matcher ICondition class which will first check if the shell is present at all and then if it's active and only then report a match.